Elastic Job sp_add_jobstep SSL Provider, error: 0- 0-The target principal name is incorrect
Elastic Job sp_add_jobstep  A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. provider: SSL Provider, error: 0-The target principal name is incorrect
I am trying to setup 'Elastic Job Agents' for the first time.  We are using Private endpoints so when        I add the Target_Group_Member, I use the 'privatelink' set up.
  EXEC jobs.sp_add_target_group_member
    @target_group_name = 'ServerGroupAnalytics',
    @target_type = 'SqlServer',
    @refresh_credential_name = 'refresh_credential',
    @server_name = 'Value.privatelink.database.windows.net'; 

But there is no where I see to add 'TrustServerCertificate=True' which is required.  Not sure where to add it.  But I believe the error that I am getting is tied to this issue.  In SSMS, If I don't have that option checked using the private link I would get the same error.
Thanks,
Daniel
But there is no where I see to add 'TrustServerCertificate=True' which is required.  Not sure where to add it.  But I believe the error that I am getting is tied to this issue.  In SSMS, If I don't have that option checked using the private link I would get the same error.
